# Selected Value for Combox not updated

Tags: c#, windows, data-binding

I need to bind an object to my Combobox and I tried to display its selected value or otherwise Current.color when I clicked a button.Here is my code

```
      public ObservableCollection<Data> Items { get; set; }
    public Data _current;
    public Data Current
    {
        get
        { return _current; }
        set
        {
            _current = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Current"));
            }
        }
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new Data() { color = names[i] });
        }
        combobox.DataSource=Items;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "color";
        Current = Items.First();
        comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", Current, "color", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
    }
    public List<Color> names = new List<Color>() { Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Blue };

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text =Current.color.ToString();
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = Current;
    }
```

The problem is label "Red" only displays onetime,when I change the selection to other color and back to the first one,Current.color does not get updated to "Red"..May I know Why is it???

Comment: is this Winforms? WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The propertyChanged event in your code is fired only when the SelectedValue property is other than its default value (i.e. "Red").
This happens because Current object is initialized to items.First().

One solution is to initialize Current object with a new Data object, that is:

```
...
Current = new Data(){ color = Color.Red }
comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", Current, "color", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
...
```

Another solution is to add binding on the Text property instead of SelectedValue one, that is:

```
...
Current = Items.First();
comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Current, "color", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
...
```

Comment: That worked..Thanks a lot..Could I know what's the effect for Text property in Databinding??

Comment: yes, the Text property refers to the text currently displayed by the combobox.
So, every time this text changes, Current object is updated.